# Unable to start a docker-compose service using docker-compose up

Tags: reactjs, node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I have 2 services in docker-compose file FE and BE.
I'm able to run the BE but not FE when I do `docker-compose` up.

The image for FE is being built but docker is unable to run the container using the `docker-compose` up.

But I'm able to run the container using `docker run -p 3000:3000 er_fe:1.0` command. and was successfully able to view the app in browser.

But if I do `docker-compose up`, the BE is starting fine. but for FE, it's giving below error.

```
easy_report@1.0.0 start /app
er_fe_container  | > react-scripts start
er_fe_container  | 
er_fe_container  | sh: react-scripts: not found
er_fe_container  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
er_fe_container  | npm ERR! syscall spawn
er_fe_container  | npm ERR! file sh
er_fe_container  | npm ERR! errno ENOENT
er_fe_container  | npm ERR! easy_report@1.0.0 start: `react-scripts start`
er_fe_container  | npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
er_fe_container  | npm ERR! 
er_fe_container  | npm ERR! Failed at the easy_report@1.0.0 start script.
er_fe_container  | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
er_fe_container  | npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
er_fe_container  | 
er_fe_container  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
er_fe_container  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-11-30T16_59_03_286Z-debug.log
```

Here's my **Dockerfile** for FE:

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  er_fe:
    build:
      context: ./er_fe
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: er_fe:1.0
    container_name: er_fe_container
    command: ["npm", "run", "start"]
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./er_fe:/app
    depends_on:
      - er_be
  er_be:
    build:
      context: ./er_be
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: er_be:1.0
    container_name: er_be_container
    command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./er_be:/app
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "easy_report",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.9.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-player": "^2.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your package.json?

Comment: @HarryHsu added.

Comment: Does your dev server work outside the docker environment? if so could you also attach the general folder structure that you tried to copy into docker container?

Answer (score 1):

There's a big difference between your `docker run` command and your docker-compose file: the volume mapping:

```
volumes:
  - ./er_fe:/app
```

This replaces the `/app` directory in the image with your `er_fe` directory on the host. That directory doesn't have all the node modules that you install with `npm install` in your Dockerfile. So they're missing and that's why your container fails.

To fix it, delete the volume mapping.

Comment: Already tried that too. Still same issue.